# commerce - add tax when creating order

Tags: commerce

I don't seem to see an ability to add tax to an order when it's created by admin through Store->Orders->Create Order. Can this be somehow configured?

I have it working on a standard checkout for a frontend user, it depends on the billing address entered. I'd like to have the same for when order is created 'manually'

Answer (score 0):

This *used* to be handled by an external module called [Commerce Checkout Admin](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_admin) 7.x-2.11 but since Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.16 this apparently came as part of core. As a result, Commerce Checkout Admin 7.x-2.12 now does not include this feature.

Since updating my site the 'Add an Order' no longer seems to calculate tax, so I am looking for this solution as well. Using:

- Drupal 7.30
- Commerce Kickstart 7.x-2.16

Comment: I discovered the controls to show the Pricing Rules and to Simulate Checkout Completion on the 'Add an Order' page are found at: admin/commerce/config/order. There you'll see two checkboxes:
`Enable the local action link on order edit forms to apply pricing rules.` and `Enable the local action link on order edit forms to simulate checkout completion. `

Comment: related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127849/how-to-calculate-tax-on-add-an-order-page-in-drupal-commerce-2-16